# how to store result from var(data) (variance function)

Tags: r, variance

I am calculating :

```
var(ORA.Pa.Close)
```

and it returns :

```
                 ORA.PA.Close
ORA.PA.Close     2.493055
```

How do I get only : `2.493055` In order to store it into a table.

For exemple

```
for (idx in seq(length(var_list))){
  stock_index = ListeTable[[idx]]
  var_index = var_list[idx]
  Valeur.Close <- stock_index[,c(4)]
  var_index = var(Valeur.Close)
  print(var_index) 
}
```

`print` returns:

```
             ACA.PA.Close
ACA.PA.Close     4.924831
             WLN.PA.Close
WLN.PA.Close     275.6803
             VIE.PA.Close
VIE.PA.Close     4.976614
               ALCHI.PA.Close
ALCHI.PA.Close      0.8265476
             SAN.PA.Close
SAN.PA.Close     51.71553
             RUI.PA.Close
RUI.PA.Close     72.45928
             ORA.PA.Close
ORA.PA.Close     2.493055
            BN.PA.Close
BN.PA.Close    35.97064
            AF.PA.Close
AF.PA.Close    7.700757
```

**How should I do in order to store variance in data table structured as below:**

```
                 Variance
ACA.PA.Close     4.924831
WLN.PA.Close     275.6803
VIE.PA.Close     4.976614
ALCHI.PA.Close      0.8265476
SAN.PA.Close     51.71553
RUI.PA.Close     72.45928
ORA.PA.Close     2.493055
BN.PA.Close    35.97064
AF.PA.Close    7.700757
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to compute price variance instead of the variance of returns? If the former is true, you only need to call `as.numeric()` on your result and the names will be dropped.

To compute it without a loop, you could use this approach:

```
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)

?quantmod

getSymbols(c("IBM", "AAPL"),
                   from = "2016/12/31",
                   to = "2018/12/31",
                   periodicity = "daily")

data <- merge.xts(IBM, AAPL)[, c('IBM.Close', 'AAPL.Close')]
result <- apply(data, 2, var)
> print(result)
 IBM.Close AAPL.Close 
 211.91255   43.17136
```